# Hyphenated subcommand in Thor

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm writing a CLI gem with Thor. Right now I have two subcommands with names that I'd like to be hyphenated. But I can't figure out how to make that work.

Here's the main class

```
module CLI
  class Base < Thor

    desc "api-token COMMAND", "Configure the API token"
    subcommand "api-token", ApiToken
```

Here's the subcommand class

```
module CLI
  class ApiToken < Thor
    include Shared

    namespace "api-token"
```

The subcommand shows up in the main `help` output, and if I enter

```
$ bundle exec bin/cli help api-token
```

it shows me the right output for the subcommands actions. So something is connecting at least.

But when I try to *use* the command, this is what I see

```
$ bundle exec bin/cli api-token set
> Could not find command "api-token".
```

The command works fine if I make it one word or use an underscore, but I really prefer a hyphen.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: Nope. I gave up on figuring it out. I'd still love to change it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `map` required, just

```
class Test < Thor
  desc 'howto-dash', "dash in command name"
  def howto_dash
    puts "dashing through the snow"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
> thor list
test
----
thor test:howto-dash  # dash in command name
```

Comment: Finally getting back to this answer. It's infuriating how simple this was, for as long as I spent on it.

Comment: I found that `thor` will always convert dashes to underscores before calling the method; and you're free of providing whatever `desc` you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering about this, you can use Thor.map to map a string to a method/command. Ex.

```
desc "Command help", "Longer command description"
def package_all
  puts "Packing..."
end
map "package-all" => "package_all"
```

Link to the documentation: [Thor#map-class_method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor#map-class_method)